# Split a text file to multiple files based on the data begin with

Tags: text, vbscript, batch-file

I'm looking for the way to split the File A into two (File B and File C) by windows batch file or vbscript. I greatlly appreciate if you can provide the sample code !!

```
File A
------------------------------
'H',123,'1st'
'D',123,'1st'
'D',123,'2nd'
'D',123,'3rd'
'H',456,'2nd'
'D',456,'1st'
'D',456,'2nd'
'D',456,'3rd'
------------------------------

File B
------------------------------
'H',123,'1st'
'H',456,'2nd'
------------------------------

File C
------------------------------
'D',123,'1st'
'D',123,'2nd'
'D',123,'3rd'
'D',456,'1st'
'D',456,'2nd'
'D',456,'3rd'
------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
findstr /bl "'H'" a.txt >b.txt
findstr /bl "'D'" a.txt >c.txt
```

Comment: So mark the question as answered (click on the check mark near the upper left hand corner of your question). That lets others know the question has been answered, it awards you 2 rep points, and the answer poster 15 points.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it programmatically like this:

```
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=," %%a in (File_A) do (
  if "%%a"=="'H'" echo %%a,%%b,%%c>>File_B
  if "%%a"=="'D'" echo %%a,%%b,%%c>>File_C
)
```

I believe that this method will probably be slower, but it will allow you more fine tuning of your conditions or manipulation of the data without having to learn REGEX (which `FINDSTR` implements poorly).

Answer (score 0):

And for completeness or educational purposes, a VBS solution.
An output stream object for each found letter is kept as the value in a dictionary.

```
Option Explicit
Dim fso, dic, ts_in, ts_out, s, key, INFILE, OUTDIR
Set fso = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")
Set dic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

INFILE = "c:\temp\infile.txt"
OUTDIR = Left (INFILE, InstrRev (INFILE, "\"))  'same folder as INFILE's

Set ts_in = fso.OpenTextFile (INFILE)
Do Until ts_in.AtEndOfStream
    s = ts_in.ReadLine
    key = Replace (Left (s, InStr (s, ",")-1), "'", "")
    If Not dic.Exists (key) Then
        Set ts_out = fso.CreateTextFile (OUTDIR & key & ".txt")
        dic.Add key, ts_out
    End If
    Set ts_out = dic(key)
    ts_out.writeLine s
Loop
ts_in.Close

For Each ts_out In dic.Items
    ts_out.Close
Next
```